# ODBC connection with oracle oraclient10g missing driver

Tags: oracle, driver

Can you help me connect `access 2013` with an `Oracle database` using `odbc`. I need a `Oracle` in `oraclient10g` driver, however I do not know how to install it. I went through many descriptions how to install that driver.

I have the database i just need to connect it to Access for a school project.

Comment: More info would help: are both the Access database and the Oracle database on the same machine or different machines? Do you have administrative access to both machines? Are you trying to connect FROM the Access database TO the Oracle database?

Comment: I'm trying to connect from my local pc (access) to a uni database (oracle) located somewhere on university servers. I have step by step manual how to set up a connection, but i miss the driver. And I cant help myself. Thats why I'm asking here.

Comment: I've just found out, that i should instal ODAC first? There should be also the driver. And i can finish the access conection...

Comment: You may download the ODBC drivers from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-096177.html  I would also suggest that  you talk with other students in your class who have succeeded, your TA (if there is one) and your professor.